# Package org.apache.commons.pool2.impl does not exist

Tags: java, maven, redis, maven-install

when i use this **maven** project,`mvn install` .

[ERROR] hint

**Package org.apache.commons.pool2.impl does not exist**

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9QyIP.png)

pom.xml about redis

```xml
        <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-redis</artifactId>
                <exclusions>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-data-redis</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                </exclusions>


            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-data-redis</artifactId>
                <version>1.8.23.RELEASE</version>
            </dependency>
        <dependency>
                <groupId>org.crazycake</groupId>
                <artifactId>shiro-redis</artifactId>
                <version>2.8.20</version>
            </dependency>
```

i saw org.apache.commons.pool2 has been downloaded in maven repo.

[package has been downloaded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p68BN.png)

but external libraries in idea does not have this package

[but not in dependency and libraries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oVLCC.png)

i try to put package `commons.pool2` into `project structure` ->`libraries`,then when i **reload** maven project ,the package `org.apache.commons.pool2` is missing from libraries and modules

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-pool2</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.0</version>
</dependency>
```

is useless，some new error will be happened in project.

Comment: put it as dependency into the pom. not in the project structure

Answer (score 0):

As I see that you are excluding `spring-data-redis` from `spring-boot-starter-data-redis`.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-redis</artifactId>
    <exclusions>
      <exclusion>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-redis</artifactId>
      </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Why are adding it back again with defined version

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-data-redis</artifactId>
  <version>1.8.23.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

The `spring-data-redis` contains `org.apache.commons » commons-pool2`

Remove both the `<exclusion>` and the `spring-data-redis` dependency

You can also try below commands to get the dependency structure

```
mvn dependency:tree
mvn help:effective-pom
```

and look for `commons-pool2`,maybe something will draw your attention like excludes or dependency overrides

Comment: I try to remove the dependency  `<exclusion>spring-data-redis` ,but it does not work. 
then i use `mvn help:effective-pom`,
**in addition to **

`
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-pool2</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.2</version>
      </dependency>
`

**there are**

`
<dependency>
        <groupId>commons-pool</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-pool</artifactId>
        <version>1.6</version>
      </dependency>

`
mybe it have an imapct？